# Ordenar listas dentro de otra lista segun el valor de un indice en estas Python

Tags: python

necesito ordenar esta lista de menor a mayor segun el ultimo valor de cada una de las listas dentro:

```
Datos_Ingreso= [[10.127,-74.950,3],[10.196,-74.935,2],[10.350,-75.040,2490],[10.196,-74.935,101]]
```

Que me quede de la siguiente manera:

```
Datos_Ingreso= [[10.196,-74.935,2],[10.127,-74.950,3],[10.196,-74.935,101],[10.350,-75.040,2490]]
```

he intentado con esto, pero solo consigo que modifique las dos primeras

```
menor=Datos_Ingreso[0][2]
im=0
for i in range(len(Datos_Ingreso)):
if Datos_Ingreso[i][2]<=menor:
menor= Datos_Ingreso[i][2]
im=i
Datos_Ingreso.insert(0,Datos_Ingreso[im])
Datos_Ingreso.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución:

```
lista = sorted(Datos_Ingreso, key = lambda x: x[-1])
```

La función `sorted` ordena. El parámetro `key` dice el criterio de ordenamiento. En este caso, usamos una función anónima (*lambda*) que usa el último elemento de cada sublista como valor de comparación.

**Demo**

```
Datos_Ingreso= [[10.127,-74.950,3],[10.196,-74.935,2],[10.350,-75.040,2490],[10.196,-74.935,101]]
lista = sorted(Datos_Ingreso, key = lambda x: x[-1])
print(lista)
```

produce

```
[[10.196, -74.935, 2], [10.127, -74.95, 3], [10.196, -74.935, 101], [10.35, -75.04, 2490]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```